# cups: HTTP_STATE_WAITING Closing for error 32 (Broken pipe)

Tags: printer, cups

On a Debian stable I've a network printer connected and shared (Epson hp1536dnf):

```
socket://ip:9100
```

from Linux clients I've:

```
ipp://IP/printers/printer1
```

The logs of the server are:

```
D [01/Sep/2017:18:21:29 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Active clients"
D [01/Sep/2017:18:21:29 +0200] [Client 33] HTTP_STATE_WAITING Closing for error 32 (Broken pipe)
D [01/Sep/2017:18:21:29 +0200] [Client 33] Closing connection.
```

The printing goes to the server but no print on the printer. From the server the printer works correctly.

EDIT: changing printer driver I solved the problem.

Comment: Can you clarify in a bit more detail what driver you changed to @PolHallen ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and I used an HP driver described in `lpinfo -m` as "requires proprietary plugin".

I had to install `hplip-plugin` from AUR.